# issues redirecting apache site in HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I have a web site running on apache2 where I needed to implement a few redirects.  They are fairly basic, but I am having problems on a specific part.

I need the following redirects to properly happen;

```
http://www.example.com ->  http://example.com
https://www.example.com  ->  https://example.com
```

Currently I have the following settings in my /conf/httpd.conf file;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

and almost the exact same thing in my /conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf file;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

EDIT - I corrected a small error in the HTTPD.CONF file above.  It actually goes to http://example.com.

ADD - The current results I am seeing is that the redirect on the http traffic seems to be working properly, but the https redirect does not.  Here is a basic summary of what I am seeing;

```
current results
http://www.example.com  ->  http://example.com  (correct)
https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com  (incorrect)
```

ADD - I checked the apache logs and could find no related errors.  If there is a specific log or logging setting I should use please let me know.

ADD - There are no redirect loops I can see and for the most part everything seems to work fine, except that my redirect isn't happening.  I did verify that the httpd-ssl.conf file is getting properly referenced.

This is an area I have little direct experience in and I am sure I am just missing something small.  I have tried researching this but have hit a wall.  If it wasn't for the fact that this is on a live site I would just experiment until I got it working.

Thanks for any help or advice you can give.

Comment: enable logging and see what it says, it'll be a lot easier to troubleshoot after you share that information)

Comment: What symptoms are you seeing? Do the redirects just not work? Redirect loop?

Comment: What Andrew Schulman said.  You've told us what you expect to happen, but not what it's actually doing.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit out of practice writing these.  I took everyones suggestions and rewrote sections above with more detail.